# AngularJS filter returns empty result on page load

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an input of which the value should be used as a filter query:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" placeholder="Movie title">
```

and a repeat directive with a filter on a property of the repeated elements:

```
<tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:{title: query}">
```

When I enter a value into the text box the results are filtered. When I delete the input value all movies are shown. So far so good. But when the page (or view) is loaded the first time the filter returns no elements and the table is empty. It seems to me that the filter either isn't properly called or with a wrong value. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: what is default value of `query` are you setting it something inside your controller?

Comment: `ng-init="query=''"`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:{title: query||'' }">
```

I think it is because query is undefined in pageload