# Searching particular fields using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have read the AngularJS documentation pertaining to filters [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) but I find it difficult to understand. I have a list of airlines, including airline name, airline country, and a flag to indicate whether the airline is deleted. Without the filter all the rows are being displayed as expected.

I need to search on all three fields and have inputs like this (yes I am using Bootstrap):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: right">
        <label for="airport-name-search" class="control-label">Airline Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input ng-model="search.airlineNameSearch" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="airport-name-search"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: right">
        <label for="country-name-search" class="control-label">Country Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input ng-model="search.countryName" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="country-name-search"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: right">
        <label for="include-deleted-search" class="control-label">Include Deleted</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input ng-model="search.includeDeleted" type="checkbox" id="include-deleted-search"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

My table looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ariline ID</th>
            <th>Airline Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
            <th>24hr Telephone</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Deleted</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr dir-paginate="airline in airlines | filter:search | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">
        <td>{{ airline.airlineId }}</td>
        <td>{{ airline.airlineName }}</td>
        <td>{{ airline.country }}</td>
        <td>{{ airline.telephoneNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ ariline.telephone24Hour }}</td>
        <td>{{ airline.emailAddress }}</td>
        <td>{{ airline.isDeleted }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I understand that custom filters cannot accept arrays of objects (well that's what I read anyway; maybe things have changed). I am struggling to construct an inline filter to search by these three fields, and I don't think I have to write a custom filter. My current attempt at a filter looks like this:

```
ng-repeat="airline in airlines | filter:search | itemsPerPage: pageSize"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

I have had some success creating a filter, like this:

```
<tr dir-paginate="airline in airlines | filter: { airlineName: search.airlineName } | filter: { country: search.countryName } | filter: { isDeleted: search.includeDeleted } | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage"><!--- ... ---> </tr>
```

but the only problem remaining is that the filter fails if the search input is empty when the page first loads. It works fine once the criteria are added and then deleted (blanked). How can I correct this?

Comment: provide a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: I've never created a jsfiddle before...will look into it.

Comment: Which version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: are you facing problem in creating `itemsPerPage` filter ?

Comment: I have had some success, please see main post

Comment: No the itemsPerPage is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Google is your friend.

I need to replace:

```
filter: { airlineName: search.airlineName }
```

with

```
filter: { airlineName: search.airlineName||'' }
```

Works a treat. Full post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118290/angularjs-filter-returns-empty-result-on-page-load).

Answer (score 0):

As of Angular v1.3, you can use this: [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter). In particular, see: [filterBy](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#filterby). I don't see why you would need `||''`, it looks like you want

```
filterBy: ['airlineName']: search.airlineNameSearch
```

where search.airlineNameSearch is the model for your input box. It will be empty to start which will return all results.